# subscribe for observerable won't execute

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I'm having some Observable subscribe issues.

Basically, I have a bunch of Observables nested into each other, and it executes as I expect, but the subscription doesn't fire for one of them.  I still have things i need to do before this returns.  Can anyone tell me why the subscribe on the one won't execute?

Thanks

```
public login(): Observable<boolean> {

return Observable.create((observer) => {
  this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
      this.setup(authResult).subscribe(ob2 => {
        console.log('This subscribe will not')
      });
  }
     });
  });
}

private setup(authResult): Observable<any> {
let t = new Observable((ob2) => {
  this.accountService.getInvite().subscribe(res => {
    if (res.status == 1) {
      let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProcessInviteComponent, {
        autoFocus: false,
        width: '35rem',
        disableClose: true,
        panelClass: ['mt-dialog-overlay']
      });
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.accountService.processInvite(result).subscribe( res => {
           this.accountService.setupUser(authResult.accessToken).subscribe( res => {
            console.log('this subscribe will fire')
           });

        });
      });
    }
  });
});
return t;
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be subscribing to the login Observable. Is that intentional?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis login is being subscribed to. I just left that out for simplicity

Comment: This is not how you should chain observables. Please use the switchMap or mergeMap operators.